# Rails: dynamic_path of link_to to different a resource name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

How can I do a `link_to` that I can modify like the object class string?

First off, I have my objects as polymorphic (book, magazine) so I need to user `link_to(@object.title, [@object.user, @object])`. This make's it polymorphic like `user_book_path` or `user_magazine_path` as expected.

My question is how can I change the `user` part to writer eg. `writer_magazine_path` or `writer_book_path`? Cause in my routes I have named user as `writer` and I'm wondering how I can do it to the `link_to` method.

**note** Don't know if I titled it correctly. Correct it if so.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Make helper for example

**In your Helper**

```
def *method_name(@object)*
  link_to "whatever" write_"#{object}"_path
end
```

Now, In your view file

```
<%= method_name(@object) %>
```

Comment: Should the link_to be a string or something cause I think you're doing interpolation on the path?

Comment: helper it's like a view file whatever you write in view that you can also write in helper so you can use link_to in helper

Comment: I haven't tried it yet but I don't think the "#{object}" would interpolate itself on the write_*_path. But I'll try it out when I get back to my code.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can make use of eval, as follows

```
<%= link_to @object.title, 
    eval("writer_#{@object.class.name.downcase)_path(pass_object_here)"} %>
```